# Where is Currency localization set for VS2012 IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp-classic, localization, iis-express

When I call `<%=FormatCurrency(myVal,2)%>` from my production IIS 7.5 ASP I get good values like `($10.00)`.

When I call it from my dev environment in VS2012 running on IIS Express I get `��-10.00`.

So I'm pretty sure currency localization is being altered in my dev environment.  But it *is* set for $ on my dev *machine* (Win7x64, [per control panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5(v=vs.90).aspx)).  Where else could this localization parameter be set or altered in this development environment?